# An unhandled exception occured xamarin.forms when i click a button in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

The code of my project:

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App2
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
    }
}
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App2"
         x:Class="App2.MainPage">

<Button Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" 
       VerticalOptions="Center" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />

 </ContentPage>
```

In every project i create in xamarin when i click a button when in the android emulator i receive this message :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoG96.png)

An unhandled exception occured.

And when i click the button in others projects it's give me the same message, please help me !

Comment: Does Page1 has any code?

Comment: yes it have it display a label with the text welcome to xamarin forms

Comment: I mean some C# code? I assume that it could be something wrong there, this looks OK for me.

Comment: nope thank you but i resolved the problem by changing this line in app.xaml.cs from MainPage = new exercice2_stack_layout.MainPage(); to Mainpage = new NavigationPage (new MainPage());

Comment: Write that below as the answer so that someone coming later may easier find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found that i have to change this line in app.xaml.cs from MainPage = new exercice2_stack_layout.MainPage(); to Mainpage = new NavigationPage (new MainPage()); to make the navigation.pushasync work perfectly .